# How to pass two arguments for a method in the HTML template?

Tags: html, angular

This is the method in app.component.ts:

```
deleteItem(collectionName:string, documentId:string){
    this.firestore.collection(collectionName).doc(documentId).delete();
  }
```

Trying to use it in app.component.html:

```
<button type="button" (click)="deleteItem(item.docId : item.colname)">delete</button>
```

I am receiving the following error message:

> Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

Comment: Did you mean to write this by any chance? `(click)="deleteItem(item.colname, item.docId)"`

Comment: Absolutely thank you! It was the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing two or more arguments - a) **they need to be in the right orde**r (ie: passed in the order that the function expects them to be passed in - which in this case is collection name first and then document id) ) and b) **they are separated by a comma not a colon**.

```
deleteItem(collectionName:string, documentId:string){
    this.firestore.collection(collectionName).doc(documentId).delete();
  }


<button type="button" (click)="deleteItem(item.colname, item.docId)">delete</button>
```

Comment: Thanx and happy coding